# Only use /etc/hosts for resolving hostnames on Linux

Tags: dns, hosts

I want to disable DNS lookups via DNS server and only resolve host names that are listed in /etc/hosts. I am on Raspbian 9. How would I set this up?

Comment: Take the reference to the DNS server out of your network configuration so that it doesn't appear in /etc/resolv.conf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove *dns* from *hosts* field in [`/etc/nsswitch.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/artful/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html):

```
hosts:          files
```

You might also want to remove the DNS servers from `/etc/resolv.conf`.